# See if a timestamp is between a specific hour

Tags: c++, unix-timestamp

I have a lot of timestamps, and data associated with it. I want to retrieve data that came from say 0800 - 0900.. What is the way to check if a timestamp falls between that?
How should i write a function that inputs two hours and returns a list of timestamps that falls inside those hours, regardless of what day it is?

like

```
std::list<uint32_t> getTimestampsBetween(uint16_t min_hour, uint16_t max_hour)
{
    if(timestamp from list of timestamp is between min_hour and max_hour)
        add it to list;

    return list;
}
```

Comment: http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/ and http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the format of the timestamps, but if they're `time_t`, you
can use `mktime` to convert a given `tm` to a `time_t`, and `difftime`
to compare two `time_t`.  Something along the lines of:

```
bool
timeIsInInterval( time_t toTest, int minHour, int maxHour )
{
    time_t           now = time( NULL );
    tm               scratch = *localtime( &now );
    scratch.tm_sec = scratch.tm_min = 0;
    scratch.tm_hour = minHour;
    time_t           start = mktime( &scratch );
    scratch.tm_hour = maxHour;
    time_t           finish = mktime( &scratch );
    return difftime( toTest, start ) >= 0.0
        && difftime( toTest, finish ) < 0.0;
}
```

(In practice, `toTest >= start && toTest < finish` is probably
sufficient.  Although the standard allows much more, I don't know of any
implementations where `time_t` is not an integral type containing the
number of seconds since some magic date.)

This supposes, of course, that you're looking for the times between the
two hours today.  If you want some arbitrary date, it's easy to modify.
If you want any date, you need to do the reverse: convert the timestamps
to a `tm`, and compare the `tm_hour` fields.

Comment: i found a crude way to do it by dividing the timestamp by 86400 and getting the no of seconds passed from 12am. That way i can get the time of day easily. i just have to multiply the hour by 3600 and voila! :)

Answer (score 2):

use `localtime`  to convert timestamp  to  `struct tm` and check if the tm_hour attribute of the structure  falls within the specified window.
Look into time.h for more information.